# CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess.exe not run on client PC

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium-embedded

I use CefSharf (84.4.10.0) in C# WPF application, she work well in my developpement PC.

But i install on my Client PC (Windows 10) without Firewall, "CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe" don't start.

First Time In windows Logger,

> Blockquote

Application Error:
Nom de l’application défaillante CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe, version : 84.4.10.0, horodatage : 0x5f45f0d1
Nom du module défaillant : KERNELBASE.dll, version : 10.0.19041.423, horodatage : 0x09cf3bbe
Code d’exception : 0xe0434352
Décalage d’erreur : 0x00129962
ID du processus défaillant : 0x2bc0
Heure de début de l’application défaillante : 0x01d6f30a3fce053e
Chemin d’accès de l’application défaillante : C:\Program Files (x86)\XXXXX\XXXXXXX\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe
Chemin d’accès du module défaillant: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
ID de rapport : 3f305b22-b018-4455-a85e-1e2d4970888e
Nom complet du package défaillant :
ID de l’application relative au package défaillant :

.NET Runtime
Application : CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe
Version du Framework : v4.0.30319
Description : le processus a été arrêté en raison d'une exception non gérée.
Informations sur l'exception : System.IO.FileNotFoundException
à CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Program.Main(System.String[])

> Blockquote

All cefsharp files is in application folder.

2nd Time, After installed :

- Microsoft Visual C++ 2012, 2013, 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64)
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2013, 2015 Redistributable (x86).

I have no log, no error but it dont run.

Have you an idea ?
Thanks,
Johan

Comment: Have you installed Visual C++? Please edit your original question and provide the full exception.